# VSC - conda works fine in GitBash, not in integrated VSC bash

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

Because of work purpose I have to switch from PyCharm to VSC.
Everything works like a charm with PyCharm (I kown I'm a funny guy at parties).

Conda is well configured on GitBash itself. I lunch the program and `(base)` environment shown. I can use conda command.

I just have installed VSC, conda is reconized since I can switch env with the help of the lower bar. But I'm used to play with the terminal and the integrated terminal (I switched to bash) seems different than the bash I can use as a standalone. The `(base)` env doesn't pop up and if I try `conda init bash` the command fail :

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong. I'm not used to Windows and I'm a bit lost with all the terminal available.

Comment: What do you mean by "VSC bash"? Are you using WSL? Or are you running the default shell which will be PowerShell or Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows you probably need to change the shell used in VSC from PowerShell to CMD or Bash by using `CRTL+P`and then searching `Terminal: Select Default Shell`.